# What is the simplest way to make my inputs move each time I click on the button on excel?

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a data base in which I want to click on a button and input all of the data that is interesting to me. But i can't figure out the simplest way to make a loop that moves the range + 1 every time I run the macro. Any ideas? Bigger

I have already tried some functions provided in other questions.

```
Sub Terreno()
    Range("A79").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("City: ")
    Range("B79").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Name: ")
    Range("C79").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Area: ")
    Range("D79").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Price: ")
    Range("F79").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Currency: ")
    Range("I79").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Status: ")
    Range("M79").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Contact: ")
    Range("N79").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("Phone: ")
    Range("O79").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = InputBox("E-mail: ")
End Sub
```

I expect when I run the macro it will change rows in every data input

Comment: Are you trying to modify the next row? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba.

Comment: Test for the last occupied row then plus 1.